# Dimension of (p,q) forms

Tags: combinatorics, multilinear-algebra

Let $E$ be a complex vector space of dimension $n$. What is the  dimension of the multilinear alternate forms on $E$ of type $(p,q)$ ?

I'm sure this is classical but I couldn't find a reference, and I'm getting mixed up in my wedge products.

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense as it stands. Are you starting with a complex manifold and looking at its complexified tangent bundle? But you're asking just for the dimension of the vector space at a point. So you have $n$ basis forms of type $(1,0)$, namely $dz_1,\dots,dz_n$, and $n$ basis forms of type $(0,1)$, namely $d\bar z_1,\dots,d\bar z_n$. Thus, the space of $(p,0)$ forms has dimension $\binom np$ and the space of $(0,q)$ forms has dimension $\binom nq$, so you get dimension $\binom np\binom nq$ for the vector space of $(p,q)$ forms.

Comment: is the problem that I didn't specify that $E$ is a *complex* vector space of complex dimension n ?

Comment: Well, what do you mean by holomorphic and anti-holomorphic if you have just a vector space? This language occurs in the setting of (almost) complex manifolds. I suppose you can talk about complex linear and conjugate-linear in various variables in terms of multilinear maps on a complex vector space. You would then need to work with its complexification to do so.

Comment: oh OK. well I do have in mind the setting of a complex manifold of course,  but this question should be purely linear algebra. But you are correct, I meant C linear and anti C linear instead of holomorphic and anti holomorphic, although I guess technically what I wrote is correct

Comment: also just to be perfectly clear : the dimension you give is a real dimension, and $n$ is the complex dimension of $E$ (which is therefore of even real dimension 2n). Am I correct ?

Comment: No, I'm giving you the dimension as a complex vector space.

Comment: OK. one last thing : is it obvious that if dimension of wedge products of (p,0) forms by (0,q) forms is the product of the dimensions ?

Comment: Yes. Think combinatorially, or use the fact that $\Lambda^{(p,q)} \cong \Lambda^{(p,0)}\otimes\Lambda^{(0,q)}$ and dimension of a tensor product :P

Answer (score 1):

[Comment-Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608080/dimension-of-p-q-forms#comment1280720_608080) by Ted Shifrin:

You have $n$ basis forms of type $(1,0)$, namely $dz_1,\dots,dz_n$, and $n$ basis forms of type $(0,1)$, namely $d\bar z_1,\dots,d\bar z_n$. Thus, the space of $(p,0)$ forms has dimension $\binom np$ and the space of $(0,q)$ forms has dimension $\binom nq$. using the fact that $\Lambda^{(p,q)} \cong \Lambda^{(p,0)}\otimes\Lambda^{(0,q)}$ (and that the dimension of a tensor product is the product of dimensions) you get dimension $\binom np\binom nq$ for the vector space of $(p,q)$ forms.